# How to create a personalized chapter heading style

Tags: sectioning, chapters, titlesec

I'm writing a book on Latex and I found a chapter heading style in a book that is interesting, but I don't find any package, or code, that gives me what I research.

The style is the following one :[image]

EDIT : Here is the code I tried:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % If you write in French
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,bbm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\definecolor{MyGrey}{RGB}{160,160,160}

\newcommand{\HUGE}{\fontsize{40}{36}\selectfont}

%%% HEADERS and FOOTERS %%%
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.05}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\textbf{\thepage}  {\color{MyGrey}$\: \blacktriangleright \:$}  \nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}  {\color{MyGrey}$\: \blacktriangleleft \:$}  \textbf{\thepage}}
\setlength{\headheight}{20pt}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\emph{ #1}}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection \emph{ #1}}{}}

\let\headruleORIG\headrule
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\color{black} \headruleORIG}
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhead{}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{\thepage}}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\makeatletter
\def\@textbottom{\vskip \z@ \@plus 1pt}
\let\@texttop\relax
\makeatother

% % Clear Header Style on the Last Empty Odd pages
\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else%
\hbox{}%
\thispagestyle{empty}% % Empty header styles
\newpage%
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother

%%% CUSTOM CHAPTER FORMAT %%%
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\normalfont}
    {\filcenter\large\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\\[4ex] \HUGE\thechapter}{4ex}
    {\filcenter\Huge\uppercase}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{30pt}[0pt]

\begin{document}

\chapter[Introduction and overview of electrode processes]{Introduction\\and overview\\of electrode\\processes}
%
\section{Introduction}
Electrochemistry is the branch of chemistry concerned with the interrelation of electrical and chemical effects. A large part of this field deals with the study of chemical changes caused by the passage of an electric current and the production of electrical energy by chemical reactions. In fact, the field of electrochemistry encompasses a huge array of different phenomena (e.g., electrophoresis and corrosion), devices (electrochromic displays, electro analytical sensors, batteries, and fuel cells), and technologies (the electroplating of metals and the large-scale production of aluminum and chlorine). While the basic principles of electrochemistry discussed in this text apply to all of these, the main emphasis here is on the application of electrochemical methods to the study of chemical systems.

\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

I don't know how to create the grey triangle bellow the "CHAPTER" name, and to increase the spacement between the letters of the word "CHAPTER". I also would like to have the same section format...

So here is my try:

[image]

So, if someone can help me, it would be nice!

Comment: Welcome to Tex. Could you edit your question to include a Minimum working example of what you have tried already. I would be benefit someone in answering if they knew what document class, packages, etc that you are using.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation of the `titlesec` package, in particular using the `display` style (cf. § Advanced Interface, Format).

Comment: i've updated my post, with my test. hope it will be sufficient !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution built around your example, made with `titlesec`. It also uses the `microtype` package to add space between the letters of "CHAPTER".

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % If you write in French
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,bbm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[letterspace=200]{microtype}

\definecolor{MyGrey}{RGB}{160,160,160}
\definecolor{OtherGrey}{RGB}{200,200,200}
\newcommand{\greytriangleright}{{\color{MyGrey}$\blacktriangleright$}}
\newcommand{\greytriangleleft}{{\color{MyGrey}$\blacktriangleleft$}}
\newcommand{\greytriangledown}{{\color{OtherGrey}$\blacktriangledown$}}

\newcommand{\HUGE}{\fontsize{40}{36}\selectfont}

%%% HEADERS and FOOTERS %%%
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.05}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\textbf{\thepage} \:\greytriangleright\: \nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark} \:\greytriangleleft\: \textbf{\thepage}}
\setlength{\headheight}{20pt}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\emph{ #1}}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection \emph{ #1}}{}}

\let\headruleORIG\headrule
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\color{black} \headruleORIG}
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhead{}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{\thepage}}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

%%% CUSTOM CHAPTER FORMAT %%%
\newlength{\trianglewidth}
\newlength{\triangleheight}
\settowidth{\trianglewidth}{\greytriangledown}
\settoheight{\triangleheight}{\greytriangledown}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\normalfont}
    {\filcenter\resizebox{6\trianglewidth}{6\triangleheight}{\greytriangledown}\\[-6ex]%
     \filcenter\MakeUppercase{\lsstyle\bfseries\chaptertitlename}\\[4ex]%
     \HUGE\thechapter}
    {4ex}
    {\filcenter\Huge\scshape\uppercase}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{30pt}[0pt]
\titleformat{\section}{\large\uppercase}{\hspace{-.5em}\llap{\greytriangleright\enspace\thesection}}{.5em}{}

\begin{document}

\chapter[Introduction and overview of electrode processes]{Introduction\\and overview\\of electrode\\processes}
%
\section{Introduction}
Electrochemistry is the branch of chemistry concerned with the interrelation of electrical and chemical effects. A large part of this field deals with the study of chemical changes caused by the passage of an electric current and the production of electrical energy by chemical reactions. In fact, the field of electrochemistry encompasses a huge array of different phenomena (e.g., electrophoresis and corrosion), devices (electrochromic displays, electro analytical sensors, batteries, and fuel cells), and technologies (the electroplating of metals and the large-scale production of aluminum and chlorine). While the basic principles of electrochemistry discussed in this text apply to all of these, the main emphasis here is on the application of electrochemical methods to the study of chemical systems.

\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: -nice -- I missed  this one -- was trying to find the xact replica of the downfacing triangle at the top centre of the title page -- has got small granules/dots -- but +1

Comment: well, thank you for your help!

Comment: I have one more demand: for the unnumbered chapter (e.g. Introduction, toc, ...), the top triangle does not appear.. how can i add it, like in this exemple : https://www.casimages.com/i/200220050447805014.png.html (the name "chapter ##) does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `memoir`, it handles a staggering assortment of chapter styles, and you can tweak them, or build your own. Take a peek at Madsen's ["Various chapter styles for the memoir class"](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/819d/dd96b058da16751fef4dcfb1efca87d351dc.pdf) for examples (with full code).